# Is there an already-made template project using Spring, JSF, PrimeFaces, SOAP and MySQL?

Tags: spring, jsf, soap, primefaces

The question says it all. Because I've been weeks already trying to see something in a Tomcat or Jetty server to try to complete my Exercise...

I'm desperate, I don't know how to make sure that every technology/dependency works correctly with the version of everything else, every move I make, i get an error, and I dont kmow what to do anymore.

The exercise is not even complex, but i cant even try to do it for this reason.

Is there a way i can download a template project? Or any software that can fix the versions of each stuff? Any suggestions...?

I tried Eclipse and Tomcat. I dont even know anymore the infinite number of errors and fixes that i did.

After that i tried with IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring or spring boot as your framework and maven as package and Dependency manager you can use spring-boot-starter-parent with parent tag with a specific version. after that you can omit version of rest of The dependencies in your pom file.
When you follow this approach all of the dependencies have the same version with Parent and all of them are match with each other.

Example :

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

You can use spring initializr with this url : https://start.spring.io/
And make your pom file or gradle file easily .
I hope this answer helps you
Thanks

Comment: Thank you, my problem now is create a container in Docker, there must be a problem with my dependencies, how can i know if all my dependencies are  compatible?

Comment: A docker container is just an isolated place where your service runs and is not relevant to the maven or gradle dependencies.if your application runs correctly , after creating docker image your container will be ok too. Use mentioned approach and then create docker image and run it.